# Error with internet connection via VBScript and QueryTables

Tags: vbscript

I want to grab some data from the website to the Excel file using VBScript (the same procedure as QueryTables connectino method in VBA).
But there is an error occuried while I try to execute my script.
The error states about "internet connection error" and "Unable to connect to Internet server"

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = true
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = true
Dim oBook, Connection
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
Connection = "URL; https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange"

With oSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection, oExcel.ActiveCell)
        .Name = "exchange"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery =False
End With
```

Comment: Can't use Excel's constants in VBScript. VBScript doesn't have access to them. So you have to look them up and type them. So in Excel's object browser look them up and copy them into your script. EG `Const xlEntirePage = 1`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The problem I mentioned above is concerned with this lines. So the application can't reach the internet server for some reason.           Connection = "URL; https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange"
With oSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection, oExcel.ActiveCell)